# Microsoft Flow does not get all the fields of a calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I am trying to read the events added using Microsoft flow, but I have observed that data for fields like `All Day Events` and `Recurrence` are not coming. Is there any way to get all the fields of a calendar.

[image]

[image]

In microsoft flow these fields are not available. I am trying to copy all items of a calendar to other calendar.

**Updated**:

I am able to create one item at a time, in below image you can see that I have directly passed body to post data to list. but it throws error.

[image]

[image]

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try HTTP Request to sharepoint:
[image]

Comment: How do we create items in other calendar from the output of this http call?

Comment: Run it once, copy the result JSON. Edit the flow, add a Parse JSON action with input the body of the response, click the "Use sample payload to generate schema" text and paste there the JSON to generate a schema. After that action, you will have all the properties of the calendar item.

Comment: But I get multiple items in my response, how to we save multiple values to properties, can we create an array here?

Comment: Yes, the Parse JSON action makes you an object with an array of items.

Comment: I have used apply to each in the last step to create list items but it is only creating list items with blank values.

Comment: To create items you can use the "Create item" action in a apply to each loop, and set all the fields with the variables from Parse JSON

Comment: If I use create item action then again `recurrence` and 'all day event` fields will not appear. So I have to do a post http action

Comment: currently the parse variables are null, how to fix this?

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Access-quot-results-quot-array-from-Send-an-HTTP-Request-to/td-p/117589